# MySQL LEFT JOIN with DISTINCT or LIMIT. Need to LEFT JOIN only one value

Tags: mysql

MySQL table `18_8_ChartOfAccounts`

```
AccountNumber  | VatReturnRowNumberForDebitTurnover
-------------------------------------------
 1             | 61
 2             | 55
```

MySQL table `2_1_journal`

```
DebitAccount  | TransactionPartnerName | Amount
-----------------------------------------------
 1            |      Name1             | 55
 2            |      Name2             | 60
```

MySQL table `18_6_TransactionPartners`

```
CompanyName
-------------------------------
 Name1
 Name2
 Name1
```

Query

```
SELECT 
AccountNumber,
DebitAccount, TransactionPartnerName, Amount,
CompanyName
FROM 18_8_ChartOfAccounts
LEFT JOIN 2_1_journal
ON AccountNumber = DebitAccount
LEFT JOIN 18_6_TransactionPartners
ON TransactionPartnerName = CompanyName
WHERE VatReturnRowNumberForDebitTurnover = '61' AND Amount = 55
```

In output necessary to get something like this

```
TransactionPartnerName | Amount
-----------------------------------------
  Name1                | 55
```

However as in table `18_6_TransactionPartners` there are two names `Name1` get

```
TransactionPartnerName | Amount
-----------------------------------------------
     Name1             | 55
     Name1             | 55
```

Instead of `SELECT` tried `SELECT DISTINCT` (the same result).

Instead of `ON TransactionPartnerName = CompanyName` tried `ON TransactionPartnerName = CompanyName LIMIT 1` (get syntax error).

May be need `GROUP BY CompanyName` somewhere.

Please, advice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT 
    TransactionPartnerName, Amount
FROM 18_8_ChartOfAccounts
    LEFT JOIN 2_1_journal ON AccountNumber = DebitAccount
    LEFT JOIN 18_6_TransactionPartners ON TransactionPartnerName = CompanyName
WHERE VatReturnRowNumberForDebitTurnover = '61' AND Amount = 55
GROUP BY TransactionPartnerName;
```

Comment: Tried and seems exactly what necessary. `GROUP BY` helps

Comment: Yes. Since the `Amount` field has always the same value for each value of `TransactionPartnerName`, the `GROUP BY` sentence is the best choice.

Comment: However, if in table `2_1_journal` there are multiple records with `Name1` instead of all records, can get only one record...

Answer (score 2):

`DISTINCT` doesn't limit number of rows in result - it just makes sure the rows are all unique.

The `LIMIT` solution is the right one. Only it must be placed at the end of the query. So the correct query should be:

```
SELECT 
    AccountNumber,
    DebitAccount, TransactionPartnerName, Amount,
    CompanyName
FROM 18_8_ChartOfAccounts
LEFT JOIN 2_1_journal
    ON AccountNumber = DebitAccount
LEFT JOIN 18_6_TransactionPartners
    ON TransactionPartnerName = CompanyName
WHERE VatReturnRowNumberForDebitTurnover = '61' AND Amount = 55
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the group by-statement in the subquery at LEFT JOIN for TransactionPartners table.

```
SELECT 
    AccountNumber, DebitAccount, TransactionPartnerName, Amount, CompanyName
FROM 18_8_ChartOfAccounts
    LEFT JOIN 2_1_journal ON AccountNumber = DebitAccount
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT CompanyName FROM 18_6_TransactionPartners GROUP BY CompanyName) ON TransactionPartnerName = CompanyName
WHERE VatReturnRowNumberForDebitTurnover = '61' AND Amount = 55
```

**edit1** : corrected column name.

Comment: Unfortunately get `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1248 Every derived table must have its own alias`. Seems that @vicentazo solution works and is very short and simple...

Comment: Thanks for idea. Changed this `LEFT JOIN (SELECT TransactionPartnerName FROM 18_6_TransactionPartners GROUP BY TransactionPartnerName) ` to `LEFT JOIN (SELECT CompanyName FROM 18_6_TransactionPartners GROUP BY CompanyName) 18_6_TransactionPartners` No error, seems get what need, but will need to test

Comment: ah, mistook the column name. But, you have to test which query has better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make relations between tables using unique keys.

Change TransactionPartnerName to TransactionPartnerId and add new column PartnerId to 18_6_TransactionPartners table and then join these tables using this new column.

```
SELECT AccountNumber, DebitAccount, TransactionPartnerName, Amount, CompanyName 
FROM 18_8_ChartOfAccounts 
    LEFT JOIN 2_1_journal ON AccountNumber = DebitAccount 
    LEFT JOIN 18_6_TransactionPartners ON TransactionPartnerId = PartnerId 
WHERE VatReturnRowNumberForDebitTurnover = '61' AND Amount = 55
```